# Узкие места производительности OpenGL

Tags: opengl

На днях провёл небольшой анализ производительности OpenGL. Выяснилось, что самый проблемный момент заключается в выводе изображения на экран, когда полигоны рисуются поверх других полигонов. Всего лишь пару тысяч плоскостей способны привести к значительным тормозам, хотя это просто мелочь для видеокарты. Судя по всему, проблемы начинаются уже на уровне вершинного шейдера. Изменение дальности обзора помогает исправить эту ситуацию, так как матричные преобразования происходят в вершинном шейднере, но всё же это не решение проблемы.

Comment: @openglprogrammer я ведь писал уже ответ на этот вопрос. И вот вы получили снова его же.

Answer (score 4):

Пара тысяч плоскостей это мелочь для вершинного шейдера. Для фрагментного шейдера это очень много, когда они рисуются поверх друг друга. Если плоскость занимает весь экран, то фрагментный шейдер сработает для каждого пикселя (для экрана 1280x1024 - 1,3 миллиона раз!). Если это всё умножить на "пару тысяч", то получится 2,6 миллиарда (в худшем случае, когда все плоскости полностью загораживают экран). Видеокарта такое плохо потянет. Даже если фрагментный шейдер очень простой, то происходит постоянная перезапись памяти. Один и тот же пиксель будет перезаписываться 2000 раз. Тест глубины поможет сократить это количество вызовов шейдера и перезаписей пикселя, если отсортировать все плоскости по удалению от камеры.

Comment: Не подскажите алгоритм?

Answer (score 2):

Алгоритм очень сложен. Если бы он был прост, его уже бы давно применяли везде и вся. Сортировать нужно, хотя бы приблизительно. 
Ещё есть способ, называемый "Запрос о преградах". В книге "OpenGL Суперкнига" (OpenGL Superbible) авторов Райта, Липчака и Хаемеля (Wright, Lipchak, Haemel) есть целая глава, посвящённая этому методу. Всё делается специальными функциями OpenGL, так что изобретать велик не придётся. Смысл в том, чтобы  сначала отобразить объекты простыми фигурами (людей с помощью параллелепипедов, сферы с помощью кубов или октаэдеров и т.д.), а потом проверить, какие из этих простых фигур не видно. Если простая фигура не видна, то не рисовать сложный объект, сопоставимый ей. Если не изменяет память, то фигуры можно загружать свои, настраивая под нужды. В любом случае почитайте.

Если что, то вот ссылка на эту главу в издательстве Вильямс:
[Запросы о преградах (pdf)](http://www.williamspublishing.com/PDF/5-8459-0998-8/part.pdf)

Comment: Вами предложенный способ мне уже известен. Меня больше интересует работа с Z-буферизацией, но ничего внятного по этой теме не встретил. 

>"Z-буферизация — в компьютерной трёхмерной графике способ учёта удалённости элемента изображения. Представляет собой один из вариантов решения «проблемы видимости». Очень эффективен и практически не имеет недостатков, если реализуется аппаратно. Программно же существуют другие методы, способные конкурировать с ним: Z-сортировка («алгоритм художника») и двоичное разбиение пространства (BSP), но они также имеют свои достоинства и недостатки. "

Comment: А в чём заключается задача? Может помогу с решением. Самому интересно. Вдруг в будущем будет такая же проблема.
P.S. Я сам занимаюсь с удовольствием программированием на OpenGL уже 2-й год. Буду стараться делиться с вами опытом. Может от вас что-нибудь мудрое подчерпну.

Comment: "Вдруг в будущем будет такая же проблема."
 Вряд ли. В играх никто не рисует тысячи перекрывающихся объектов.
"Я сам занимаюсь с удовольствием программированием на OpenGL уже 2-й год."
 Кстати, я тоже второй год.

Comment: Ну так всё же, в чём задача? Хотя бы в общих чертах. Зачем вам столько перекрывающихся полигонов? Деревья что ли рисуете?

Comment: Наверное, он хочет сделать воксельный движок. Сделает 10000 параллельных плоскостей, ещё 10000 перпендикулярных им плоскостей и ещё 10000 перпендикулярных другим плоскостям плоскостей. Получится решётка из кубиков. Лишние пиксели будет отбрасывать discard'ом, чтобы "выточить" из него модель. Только вряд ли у него что-то получится таким способом...

Answer (score 2):

OpenGL использует z-буфер, чтобы заслонённые пикселы не появлялись на экране. Но вся проблема в том, что даже если он их не рисует и не вызывает фрагментный шейдер, то он всё равно их !обрабатывает!, хотя бы потому, что он сравнивает значения их глубины со значением в z-буфере. А теперь давайте представим, что будет,если единственный ближайший полигон заслонил все остальные? Конечно же, каждый заслонённый примитив будет обрабатываться, к каждому из них применятся алгоритм растеризации (для того чтобы узнать положение пиксела на экране), и, конечно же, значение каждого обрабатывающегося пиксела будет сравниваться со значением в z-буфере, с последующим отбасыванием самого пикслела. Ненужная работа! Отсюда и тормоза! А нам такой порнографии не надо. Премудрости с z-буфером в принципе не помогут. Надо вообще отсекать невидимые примитивы, чтобы не выполнялась их растеризация. Вопрос: как?

Comment: Вы правильно начали. Зачем их обрабатывать, если они всё равно не рисуются? Я считаю можно либо просто отсекать ненужные полигоны, либо рисовать их сколько хочешь, но за место полигонов отсекать ненужные пиксели. Это в некоторых случаях может быть проще, так как теряет значение сама сложность сцены.  Вам что-нибудь известно о ручной работе с буфером глубины внутри вершинного шейдера? Неплохо  было бы отсеять все ненужные пиксели уже на стадии вершинного шейдера, чтобы при поступлении во фрагментный, ему не приходилось выполнять лишних вычислений.

Comment: "Неплохо было бы отсеять все ненужные пиксели уже на стадии вершинного шейдера, чтобы при поступлении во фрагментный, ему не приходилось выполнять лишних вычислений." Боюсь такая штука не прокатит. На сколько я знаю, вершинный шейдер никак не влияет на фрагменты, он только работает с параметрами вершин, которые затем линейно интерполируются для использования фрагментными шейдерами. А отсеивание по глубине происходит до вызова фрагментного, чтобы исключить лишние вычисления. С геометрическими шейдерами не работал, но есть предположение, что они могут помочь, но я про них толком ничего не знаю.

Answer (score 1):

В любом случае, ему нужно делать так, чтобы треугольники, фрагменты которых будут полностью отсеяны в конечном изображении, не попадали на конвеер. Я понимаю, что говорю очевидные вещи, но решение проблемы кроется в понимании её мелких деталей. Мне кажется, что алгоритмы Z-Буферизации тут никоем образом не помогут. Нужно работать с нечто большим, а именно, с треугольниками. И по
тому я думаю, что запросы о преградах будут хорошим решением (не факт, что лучшим, но всё же хорошим).

Comment: Смысл запроса о преградах в том, чтобы рисовать низкополигональные фигуры вместо высокополигональных и проверять, видна ли она или нет. А плоскость итак низкополигональная, да и тормоз не в этом, а в пикселях. Мне кажется, что в его случае ничего не поможет. Только если сортировка по удалённости от камеры. В общем, похоже его этот вопрос уже не интересует. Он ничего не пишет.

Comment: Я думаю, эффективны в этом случае два подхода. Можно работать как с треугольниками, так и с отдельными пикселями. Возможны разные варианты. Z-буферизацию я бы не спешил сбрасывать со счетов.  Как раз она могла бы очень пригодиться. Есть определенные идеи на этот счёт. Жаль только, что литературы в контексте OpenGL на эту тему совсем мало.
 
Но всё равно спасибо за ответы. Буду над этим работать.

Comment: >Z-буферизацию я бы не спешил сбрасывать со счетов. Как раз она могла бы очень пригодиться.  

 Z-буфер и так обычно включён. Без него далёкие объекты рисовались бы поверх ближних. Он нужен только тогда, когда у тебя рисуются сначала ближние объекты, а потом дальние. Тогда он и отсекает ненужные фрагменты. Больше Z-буфер ничего не делает.

Answer (score 0):

Включите проверку глубины, чтобы отсекались невидимые пикселы:
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)